# How can I install the default Microsoft SQL Server that comes with VS22?

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, entity-framework

On my PC, I messed up the default installation of the SQL Server that comes with VS22.

I managed to install SQL Server manually again, but I have to write a database class library using EF Core.

For that I have a connection string as follows:

```
Data Source=(localdb)\\MSSQLLOCALDB;Initial Catalog=TestDB;Integrated Security=True
```

I've been told that EF will create the database as needed after the name given in the connection string.

This works fine on my new laptop on which I did not touch the SQL Server. On my PC it does not work though.

What do I have to do to get the "default" installation of the SQL Server?

Comment: Docs here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/sql-server-express-localdb?view=sql-server-ver16

Answer (score 2):

You can install LocalDB through the Visual Studio Installer, as part of the Data Storage and Processing workload, the ASP.NET and web development workload, or as an individual component.

The steps in Visual Studio Installer are as follows:

First select Modity, then select SQL Server Express LocalDB in Installation details. Hope it helps you.
[image]
[image]

Comment: Thanks, I already tried removing, and then adding the Data Storage and Processing, but I did not pay attention to the list on the right. Thanks!

Comment: Okay I tried it again, still does not work.

Comment: Ok, but this is indeed LocalDB from the visual studio installer.
It is recommended that you perform visual studio repair in the installer first and then reopen. If it still doesn't work, can you clarify your problem and show the warning from visual studio, which helps better resolve your problem.

Comment: Tried that already. There is no warning from visual studio. Only if I try to update the database using 'dotnet ef database update' in the developer power shell, I get an error saying that no connection could be made.

Comment: OK, I will research and update my answer.

Comment: @trauni Did you find a solution to this? I am having the same issue. After VS installation the localdb is just not there.